# CardStackView adding spots with database information

Tags: android, database

Sorry if this post is not correctly filled but ill try to do my best. I am attempting to create an android app with android studio where i need a TinderLike swipe holder.

For this purpose i am using this library: [CardStackView](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView)

Everything is working fine if i use the default code to populate the pictures.

```
private List<TouristSpot> createTouristSpots() {
    List<TouristSpot> spots = new ArrayList<>();
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Yasaka Shrine", "Kyoto", "https://source.unsplash.com/Xq1ntWruZQI/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Fushimi Inari Shrine", "Kyoto", "https://source.unsplash.com/NYyCqdBOKwc/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Bamboo Forest", "Kyoto", "https://source.unsplash.com/buF62ewDLcQ/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Brooklyn Bridge", "New York", "https://source.unsplash.com/THozNzxEP3g/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Empire State Building", "New York", "https://source.unsplash.com/USrZRcRS2Lw/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("The statue of Liberty", "New York", "https://source.unsplash.com/PeFk7fzxTdk/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Louvre Museum", "Paris", "https://source.unsplash.com/LrMWHKqilUw/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Eiffel Tower", "Paris", "https://source.unsplash.com/HN-5Z6AmxrM/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Big Ben", "London", "https://source.unsplash.com/CdVAUADdqEc/600x800"));
    spots.add(new TouristSpot("Great Wall of China", "China", "https://source.unsplash.com/AWh9C-QjhE4/600x800"));
    return spots;
}
```

But when i try to change the default population code with a code that retrieve information from a database, nothing is displayed anymore.

```
private List<TouristSpot> createTouristSpots() {
    final List<TouristSpot> spots = new ArrayList<>();

    String url = AppData.api + "radar_2.php";

    alerttext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    SharedPreferences token = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(AppData.sp_user_info, 0);
    String user_id = token.getString(AppData.sp_user_id, "0");
    UserData userData=new AppData().getUserData();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("user_id", user_id);
    params.put("number", String.valueOf(n));
    params.put("gender", userData.getLooking_gender());
    params.put("looking_age_start",userData.getLooking_age_start());
    params.put("looking_age_end", userData.getLooking_age_end());
    params.put("latitude", userData.getLatitude());
    params.put("longitude", userData.getLongitude());
    params.put("distance", "100");

    CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            if (n == 1)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("MATCHDATALIST", response.toString());
                editor.commit();
            }

            try
            {

                String str = response.getString("Error");

                if (str.equals("None"))
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Responsedata");
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    for (int i = 0; jsonArray.length() > i; i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        spots.add(new TouristSpot(jsonObject.getString("user_id"),jsonObject.getString("username"),jsonObject.getString("hometown"),jsonObject.getString("age"),jsonObject.getString("gender"),jsonObject.getString("profile_image"),jsonObject.getString("interests"),jsonObject.getString("distance")));
                    }

                    alerttext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.getString("Error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError response)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), spots.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return spots;
}
```

In my OnCreateView, i am calling the function reload();

```
private void reload() {
    cardStackView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter = createTouristSpotCardAdapter();
    cardStackView.setAdapter(adapter);
    cardStackView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private TouristSpotCardAdapter createTouristSpotCardAdapter() {
    final TouristSpotCardAdapter adapter = new TouristSpotCardAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    adapter.addAll(createTouristSpots());
    return adapter;
}
```

I did checked the JSONArray to string and all information retrieved from the database is inside it.

PS: the TouristSpot is adapted to contain all the variables from the database.

If some one could bring me on the correct path to make it working with values retrieved from my database, i would be very gratfull

Sincerely,
Jeremy